# Add alert after page load - TYPO3

Tags: javascript, jquery, typo3

I have the standard bootstrap package and want to show an alert after the page is beeing laoded. May the alert will only shown at the index-site.

Anybody know how to do this?

I tried to include own javascript, but that doesnt worked for me..

TS:

```
page.includeJS.file1 = fileadmin/myTemplates/alert.js
```

alert.js:

```
window.onload = function () {
    alert('My Alert!');
};
```

Comment: Is the file actually getting included?

Comment: No, it isnt --> my problem?

Comment: It's definitely the core of the problem then. I don't know typo3 though so I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: A search for `typo3 include javascript file` finds this: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/t3jquery/ExtT3Jquery/Configuration/AddExtraJavascript/Index.html possibly helpful

Comment: Check if the file path is spelled correctly and then clear all caches.

Comment: @RenéPflamm : path is correctly

Comment: @Pekka웃 , its the same source i looked for. But it wont inlcude. I include succesfully a CSS file: `page.includeCSS.myCustomStylesheet = fileadmin/css/bootstrap.css`

Answer (score 0):

Found an solution. I looked for the path of an already includes js file and paste my code in. 
I think it isnt the perfect solution, but it works first.

file i added my script: `/typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Libs/modernizr...`